# installing Debian on mac a different mac partition

Tags: macos, usb, partition, startup

1. I **disabled the SIP** (system integrity protection)
2. I installed **refind-bin-0.13.3.1**
3. I erased the USB into     **FAT**
4. I booted the Debian on the USB using **DD**

   1. `diskutil list`
   2. `sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2`
   3. `sudo dd if=~/Desktop/Debian.iso of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m`
   4. I got an alert:

   > The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.
5. When I restarted the Mac, I can't boot from the usb , I get this error:

   > Not Found while loading legacy loader.

How can I get Debian installed?

Could the be because the image is corrupted(this is the third image?

Comment: What model/year is your Mac? Exactly which Debian file did you download?

Comment: MAC version : retina 13 inch 2015

Comment: the Debian version : firmware-testing-amd64-netinst.iso
i also downloaded two other one but i changed their names..